# Layout not working on asp.net core 3.0 for user profile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

On Asp core 3.0 my layout page is not working for a user when they click their profile "Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_layout.cshtml"

When I click on the default email after logging in I get Manage/Index.cshtml but no layout details. Like the navigation, links to forgot passwords etc are not displaying. I have no idea what can cause this.

I put it against other projects and see any discrepancies and cannot find any reason why my layout is not displaying.

Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_layout.cshtml

```
@{
Layout = "/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
```

Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Profile";
  ViewData["ActivePage"] = ManageNavPages.Index;
}
```

Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Trying to see what I'm missing or any other place to check to get the layout page to display.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your expected layout? For default, it will be [Manage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCmPm.png). In general, if you could sigin, you should know the password, why did you want to show forget password for `Manage` page?

Comment: I want to use the default layout when you create a new asp.net core app. When you click your email it takes you to your manage page. Im missing my default layout, with the side navigations for change password, edit profile, download personal data etc. All I'm getting is a form with email and phone number, the Manage/_Layout.cshtml is not rendering

Comment: Share us your current result? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I attached screenshots, the layout I want is not rendering

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? For `Profile`, it is in `_ManageNav.cshtml` and used with `<partial name="_ManageNav" />` in `Pages/Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue which I suspect happens when you replace the services.AddDefaultIdentity call in startup.ConfigureServices - In my case I replaced it with AddIdentity as I needed to pass the RoleManager to my controllers.

There is most probably a more elegant solution to this problem but I gave up looking for one as I find this whole new functionality to be poorly documented.

Here is how I solved for this:

I am assuming you have scaffolded the Identity pages already - If not please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

In the page under Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage_Layout.cshtml modify the layout location to:

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Now in your Index page Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\Index.cshtml you also need to explicitly set a layout page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
}
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Profile";
    ViewData["ActivePage"] = ManageNavPages.Index;
}
```

You'll also have to explicitly set this layout in all other pages under that folder.

Comment: Second half doesnt seem necessary anymore. Just setting
`Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` in `Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\_Layout.cshtml` solved my issue in a Net Core 3.0 Web MVC project (After scaffolding all my pages)

Comment: Not sure what the differences are but I'm on a 3.1 core MVC project with identity area scaffolded by default, and still had to add the `Layout = ` line in the `Index` page. This is of course after replacing `services.AddDefaultIdentity` it worked fine before that.

Comment: It is 2021 now, and this also solves exact problem in .NET 5.

Comment: It's worth noting this should be changed to `/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` if you're using blazor..

Comment: THANKS! Its 2023 now and this solved my issue in .net 6... this shit took hours, very poor documented ******* ...

Comment: For people that still do use this "approved" answer, please use the answer that suggest to use ".AddDefaultUI()" instead! Instead of changing N amount of files you will just add 1 line in your startup and it is done.

Answer (score 10):

Use `AddDefaultUI()` in startup class when setting

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>().AddDefaultUI()
```

Answer (score 3):

Update.

To solve issue install `Microsoft.AspCoreNet.Identity.UI` NuGet Package and add AddIdentity.

```
 services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();
```

But it comes with a cost. Adding AddDefaultUI() solved the issue of ActivePage, but it created another as stated above. AddDefaultUI() caused my general layout to disapear. I then applied the solutions sugggested above and got the layout back, but then ActivePage disapeared again.

Instead of spending too much time, I deleted all files in the Identity area and scaffolded Identity. TaDa, both ActivePage and my layout work perfectly.

I'm using .Net Core 5.0.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore#identity-adddefaultui-method-overload-removed

Comment: Well, in the mean time I realized I wasn’t entirely correct. If you install the nuGet package Microsoft.AspCoreNet.Identity.UI(it is updated to version 5.0.0) and .AddDefaultUI is available again. It did the trick... BUT, then I lost my general layout. I tried to fix this as described and got the layout back, though I then lost the Activepage... I therefor deleted the identity area a scaffolded Identity... tada, everything is good, except for some extra coding is needed here and there... btw. I’m using  Core 5.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just put ViewStart.cshtml in the wrong catalog.
I should have put this file in the Views folder, but I put _ViewStart file in Views/Shared together with _Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the partial class `_ManageNav.cshtml` to your Layout.
Just before `RenderBody()`:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <partial name="_ManageNav" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
            <main role="main">
                @RenderBody()
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
```